# URL reference width continues after margin

Tags: width

does anyone has this problem or can solve it, please?
I added the references through Mendeley application desktop. Everything is fine except the URL width size.
If it is too big it continues across the page size and margin size.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{/home/Thesis.bib}

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}`? Otherwise please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) next time please post something others can test. Sniplets like this does not give us much to go on. But I agree with samcarter.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,breaklinks=true}
\begin{document}
something here ...
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\bibliography{bibliog}
\end{document}
```